# Implementation of the Phase Estimation algorithm

Tags: qiskit, hamiltonian-simulation, quantum-fourier-transform, quantum-phase-estimation

I've been working on implementing quantum phase estimation in Qiskit for a $2^n \times 2^n$ Hamiltonian as part of my bachelor project, I'm using Trotterization as my Hamiltonian simulation of choice and can't quite get it to work. All my tests of the individual parts of the circuit seem correct at a glance and yet it isn't working properly.

The code is available [here](https://github.com/gozmit97/Bachelor-Project-Code/blob/main/Bachelor%20Project%20fixed.ipynb). To go through the relevant aspects of the code quickly, I firstly define `QFT_dagger`, then implement three functions that allow for Hamiltonian simulation (`pauli_traces`, `exp_product` and `decompose`). Last function before running the code, is `PhaseEst`, that runs the full phase estimation algorithm, using the functions mentioned prior.

I've tried running this for the Pauli $X$ gate as my Hamiltonian and with values of $t$ mostly ranging from $1$ to $5$ and $r = (t^2/\epsilon)$, with $\epsilon$ being the desired error, usually of size $1$ to $0.1$. This seems to give best results for $t = 1$ if at all reasonable results. I've also tried replacing my Hamiltonian simulation code with that of fellow user  [Davit Khachatryan](https://github.com/DavitKhach/quantum-algorithms-tutorials/blob/master/Hamiltonian_simulation.ipynb).

If anyone might have an inkling as to what may be causing the implementation to fall flat, then kindly let me know. Additionally, if further information is required, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hey, I did go through the code once and I was wondering what was the `h_temp` matrix that you specified ? If that was the Hadamard matrix, then there is the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ factor missing from it.

Comment: The $2 \times 2$ Hamiltonian $H = X +Z$, which is why the fraction $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ isn't there. It was just an alternative to the T gate above for testing on.